# The new headers are not added with the interceptor

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I want to add headers to all HTTPClients in my Angular 8 application. This is my interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private toaster: ToastrService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    alert('Interceptor!');

    // Set headers
    const headers = req.headers;

    // Set this header for security
    headers.set('test', 'value');

    const authReq = req.clone({ headers });

    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

The alert is executes but the test header is not added to the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official docs:

> You can't directly modify the existing headers within the previous
>   options object because instances of the HttpHeaders class are
>   immutable.
>
> Use the set() method instead. It returns a clone of the current
>   instance with the new changes applied.

You need to clone the request and set headers there.

```
const newReq =  req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('test', 'value') });
return next.handle(newReq);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go ,

1) You can use existing and add new with following, and can be placed in some utility to be reused for all intercepting request

2) Override headers with new or old, depending on your requirement

```
 setRequestHeaders(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpHeaders {
    const headerSettings: { [name: string]: string | string[]; } = {};
    // GET ALL EXISTING HEADERS
    for (const key of req.headers.keys()) {
      headerSettings[key] = req.headers.getAll(key);
    }

    // ADD NEW HEADERS
    headerSettings[COMMON_CONSTANTS.HEADERS.AUTHORIZATION] = 
        : 'Bearer some-random-token';
    headerSettings[COMMON_CONSTANTS.HEADERS.CACHE_CONTROL] = 'max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate';   

    return new HttpHeaders(headerSettings);
  }
```

Now clone request with these new headers

```
this.authReq = this.authReq.clone({
                headers:
                    this.someService.setRequestHeaders(this.authReq)
            });
```